# PHP one line get input value and use in PHP ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, input

About the example from [W3SCHOOL AJAX Database](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp) (my environment CentOS 7, PHP 7.4) - the one is simple but based on dropdown select onchange

```
<select name="customers" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
```

I'm trying to do the same but get value from an input field - but something is wrong with syntax or logic. I've tried
HTML

```
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;"><input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="myInput" id="myInput"><button type="submit" onclick="showCustomer(<?php echo $_GET['myInput'] ?>)">Test from myInput HTML</button></div><div id="txtCustomer"> </div>
```

PHP

```
echo "<div style=\"float: left; text-align: center;\"><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Type something...\" name=\"myInput\" id=\"myInput\"><button type=\"submit\" onclick=\"showCustomer(".$_GET['myInput'].")\">Test from myInput PHP</button></div><div id=\"txtCustomer\" style=\"text-align: left; font-size: 14pt;\"> </div>";
```

but no success.
If I use STATIC predefined value inside showCustomer function like

```
showCustomer('active')
```

everything works, but no one of above variations

```
onclick=\"showCustomer(".$_GET['myInput'].")\">
```

or

```
onclick="showCustomer(<?php echo $_GET['myInput'] ?>)">
```

Thx for any ideas or hints to try,

Comment: You can't use `<?php echo` there, since that runs when the page is being created, not while the user is editing the form.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('myInput').value`

Comment: I would advise you to use different quotation marks inside `echo` statements. You can use`'` for beginning and ending `echo` and `"` inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript in the argument, not PHP, since PHP doesn't run until after the form is submitted. Your code will use the value of `$_GET['myInput']` that existed when the page was being created, not whatthe user entered now.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="showCustomer(document.getElementById('myInput').value)">Test from myInput HTML</button>
```

Comment: Yes, already tested and works ! Thx ! Very clear and useful solution.